# How to change the transaction level to dirty read in a c++ builder application

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-xe5

I'm trying to follow these steps.  It's kinda dated but it seems like this is what I need.

http://www.drbob42.com/examines/examin95.htm

In the DBX4 section, the user did the following in Delphi.

```
  DBXTransaction := SQLConnection1.BeginTransaction(TDBXIsolations.ReadCommitted);
  try
    // do your work...
    SQLConnection1.CommitFreeAndNil(DBXTransaction);
  except
    SQLConnection1.RollBackFreeAndNil(DBXTransaction);
    raise
  end;
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in c++

```
TDBXTransaction* pDBXTransaction;
pDBXTransaction = pDBXSQLConnection->BeginTransaction(xilDIRTYREAD);
try
{
    ClientDataSetList = GetNodesInTree(FReleaseNodeID, SelNodesMasterTbl, lNodesDetailTbl);
    pDBXSQLConnection->CommitFreeAndNil(pDBXTransaction);
}
catch (Exception &E) 
{
    pDBXSQLConnection->RollbackFreeAndNil(pDBXTransaction);
}
```

However, I'm getting a TDBXError with message 'unassigned code' exception.  It seems like I'm missing something but I haven't been able to find a solution online.

I'm using C++ Builder XE 5
And I'm trying to do this through a DBX connection to a Interbase database.

Comment: You did not say which line of code is throwing the exception, or show what `GetNodesInTree()` is actually doing.

Comment: BTW, your `BeginTransaction()` should be outside of the `try`, just like the Delphi code showed. Or wrap the work code in another `try/catch`. The point is to create a transaction, THEN enter a `try`, THEN have its `catch` call `RollBackFreeAndNil()`. If you put `BeginTransaction()` inside the `try` and it fails, the `catch` would try to call `RollBackFreeAndNil()` on an uninitialized transaction pointer.

Comment: The exception occurs in the BeginTransaction line.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `TDBXIsolations::ReadCommitted`, like the Delphi code does, instead of using `xilDIRTYREAD` (`TDBXIsolations::DirtyReadd`)?

Comment: No. I tried what you suggested and I still get the exception.  Thanks for your help, but we were just told that interbase does not support dirty reads, so we will need to look at another solution.